# Ubuntu 14.04 > 18.04 ssh says "invalid format"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I recently upgraded a host from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 and when I try to use `ssh` under 18.04 I get the error message `key_load_public: invalid format`.

The public key portion of the keypair I use on this host (and the remote) looks like this:

```
command="/root/bin/rsync_only" ssh-rsa AAAAB...kEzWH0cMQ== root@vargas
```

It seems if I remove the `command=` portion, I don't get the `invalid format` error. It has worked fine for years. Anyone know why this is a problem now?

**/root/bin/rsync_only**

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
   *\&*)
            echo "Rejected"
   ;;

   *\;*)
            echo "Rejected"
   ;;

   rsync\ --server*)
            $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
   ;;

   *)
            echo "Rejected"
   ;;
esac
```

**ssh -vvv**

```
# ssh remote_host -i ~/.ssh/id_rsync -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "remote_host" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remote_host [10.10.16.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
key_load_public: invalid format
...
```

**ssh and -vvv output from Ubuntu 14.04**

```
ubuntu-14.04 # ssh remote_host -i ~/.ssh/id_rsync     
Rejected
Connection to remote_host closed.

ubuntu-14.04# ssh remote_host -i ~/.ssh/id_rsync -vvv
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remote_host [10.10.16.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsync" as a RSA1 public key
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'command="/root/bin/rsync_only"'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
...
```

Comment: Is `/root/bin/rsync_only` accessible by the user and does it run correctly if invoked from the shell?

Comment: yes, it exists on both local and remote. I've added it above. When executed locally on the upgraded 18.04 host (without arguments) it exits with `Rejected` (exit code 0) which is how it is intended to work.

Comment: And is it accessible and executable by the user whose key this question concerns? Note that the client side of things is unimportant as the script would be executed on the side where the key is used for authentication.

Comment: I belive so. permissions on (local side) `/root/bin/rsync_only` are `-rwxr-xr-x  root:root`. User `root` is running `ssh`. Parent directory `/root` and `/root/bin` are `drwx------  root root`

Comment: Note that accessibility depends not only on the file itself but on the permissions on `/root` and on `/root/bin` (both need at least `x` permissions for the particular user or the user's group).  Is the user the root user or are they in the root group? If not, they would not be able the access the file.

Comment: added `ssh -vvv` output above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command="/root/bin/rsync_only" ssh-rsa AAAAB...kEzWH0cMQ== root@vargas
```

Remove the `command="/root/bin/rsync_only"` text from the public key file. The public key file should start with `ssh-rsa`, and it should contain one long line of text.

The `command="/root/bin/rsync_only"` directive is something you can add to the [`authorized_keys` file](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) on an ssh *server* to make the *server* restrict the key to running a particular command. It's not something you can add to a public key file, and it's not meaningful to an ssh *client* like `ssh`.

Comment: Yep. I figured out how to get rid of the error, just wondering if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: @ServerFault Huh, here I was assuming you were talking about the public key in the `authorized_keys` file... No, adding `command=...` to the _public key file_ itself should _never_ have worked. You probably just got mixed up between the two files, probably?

Comment: *shrug* there is no error printed when running under ssh version `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`. I've been using seven different public keys, with different command restrictions, on the same server since 2014. Having the restrictions in the pubkeys makes it handy for copying out to new hosts.  Perhaps it's always been an error/warning but the message for this is new with `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`

Comment: Ok I went back to the 14.04 host and ran `ssh -vvv` and it does complain about the pubkey with `Incorrect RSA1 identifier`. When run without `-vvv`, the warning message does no appear. Guess I should have tried that first. I'm going to mark this as the answer so anyone else searching for this can find it all in the same thread. Thanks for all the help @Kusalananda